# Notificaciones en laravel al realizar una insercicon en mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, notificaciones

me ha surgido una duda de como podria notificar a un usuario al momento que llene algun formulario y este sea enviado a una tabla en mysql si se inserto correctamente lanzar un mensaje, en caso contrario notificarlo
este es mi codigo en donde hago una inserccion con un procedimiento almacenado

```
function insertBranchInformation(Request $request)
{


    if($request->input('Cp'))
    {
        $cp="";
        $estado="";
        $municipio="";
        $empresa="";
        $data=DB::statement('CALL sucursal(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',[

            $request->input('Estado'),
            $request->input('Municipio'),
            $request->input('Nombre_Colonia'),
            $request->input('Cp'),
            $request->input('Calle1'),
            $request->input('Calle2'),
            $request->input('Numero_Interior'),
            $request->input('Numero_Exterior'),

            $request->input('Sucursal'),
            $request->input('Telefono'),
            $request->input('Extension'),
            $request->input('Email'),
            $request->input('nempresa'),
            "insertar"
        ]);
        return view('register_branch_office.branch',compact("estado","municipio","cp","empresa"));
    }
```

lo que respecta al codigo

```
<div class="formulario_registro">

        <form action="{{url('/registro/sucursal/empresa')}}" method="POST">
                {{csrf_field()}}
            @if($estado=="" || $estado!="" || $cp=="" || $cp!="" || $empresa=="" || $empresa!="")
            <div class="direccion">
                <h3>Direccion de registro</h3>
                <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                        <label>Estado</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="Estado" value="{{$estado}}" class="form-control" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                        <label>Municipio</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="Municipio"  class="form-control" value="{{$municipio}}" id="municipio">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                        <label>Colonia</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="Nombre_Colonia" id="colonia" class="form-control">
                        <div id="listar_colonia"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="Cp" value="{{$cp}}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="nempresa" value="{{$empresa}}">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                        <label>Calle1</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="Calle1" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                        <label>Calle2</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="Calle2" class="form-control" >
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                        <label>Numero Exterior</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="Numero_Exterior" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                        <label>Numero Interior</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="Numero_Interior" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                @endif

            <div class="bussiness_data">
                <h3>Datos de la Sucursal</h3>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                        <label>Nombre de la sucursal</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="Sucursal" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                        <label>Telefono</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" name="Telefono" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                        <label>Extension</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="Extension" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                        <label>Email</label><br>
                        <input type="email" name="Email" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                </div>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" class="form-control" Value="Guardar">
            </div>
        </form>
```

espero y alguien me pueda orientar de como mandar esos avisos al usuario para saber si pudo realizar el registro con exito, ya que veo que en laravel no se manejan los try catch con php o al menos he investigado y no se maneja de tal forma

Answer (score 0):

podrias comprobar si la consulta fue bien efectuada con 
if($data) {
      return 
} else{
      return
}
Y para devolver un mensaje podrias ver lo que son los mensajes flash. 
O crear una variable donde sea el status del mensaje por ejemplo,
 $message = 'success'
 Luego retornas ese valor como:
 'message' => $message 
Y lo utilizas en la vista para mostrar tu mensaje.
Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Muchas gracias lo voy a probar, se te agardece